# Dosbox interrupt vectors

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

So I'm self-teaching myself assembly and I've got to the point where my curiousity is piqued enough to want to manipulate the interrupt vectors, to lark about. So I have MASM and Debug, I run it and dump the memory at the first segment and see this:

[image: Memory dump]

It doesn't look like an interrupt vector as there is no jump until address 6 - by which time I presume the second interrupt vector at byte 4 has already started? Or am I missing something in my understanding?

Comment: Please include code as text in a `code` section and not as image.

Comment: *I'm self-teaching myself assembly*  Is there a particular reason you want to start with such ancient assembly?

Comment: They are vectors (pointers to functions) not code. The code is in the place pointed to. So for the first entry that would be `F000:1060` (x86 is little endian). `F000` is typically the BIOS ROM.

Comment: @Waqar x86 (both 16 and 32 bit variants) are *extremely* well-known and documented. I would guess that there are more resources on the Internet on x86 than for all other architectures combined. Which makes me wonder what resources the OP is using, because this is one part that should be easy to find out about.

Comment: I'm using online resources mainly, though they seemed to suggest that the vector was 4 bytes that jumped to some location. But I was mainly wondering is DOSBox does something funny. And that was the answer I was looking for, they are pointers, not jump code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I think Waqar's point was why bother with legacy-BIOS booting, 16-bit mode, and DOS.  None of those are relevant for much of anything these days; modern x86 systems normally boot with UEFI for the firmware to load code from disk. The CPU itself does still power on in 16-bit unreal mode to execute the firmware ROM, but unless you're validating a motherboard or something there's not a lot of reason for using 16-bit mode. It's not a great choice for learning the basics; segmentation and limited addressing modes make everything more complicated than a 32-bit flat memory model.

Comment: There is little to be gained from disassembly of tables or data areas. A disassembler tries to present them as if they are executable code. Especially ms-dos DEBUG is a rather blunt tool. Note at address `0006` the `JO` is not a "jump" instruction as such but what is more usually known as a "branch" instruction, that just happens to look like that to the disassembler.

Comment: ... look at another `JO` at address `0012` which apparently directs to `0014` where there isn't a valid instruction. That series of `JO` instructions would be rather pointless because they direct to the next instruction, where the `IP` would be anyway.